# Not getting any data entry with 'find_all' while scraping Spotify Charts webpage

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to scrape the spotify charts containing top 200 songs in India on 2022-02-01. My python code :

```
#It reads the webpage.
def get_webpage(link):
    page = requests.get(link)
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
    return(soup)

#It collects the data for each country, and write them in a list.
#The entries are (in order): Song, Artist, Date, Play Count, Rank
def get_data():
    rows = []
    soup = get_webpage('https://spotifycharts.com/regional/in/daily/2022-02-01')
    entries = soup.find_all("td", class_ = "chart-table-track")
    streams = soup.find_all("td", class_= "chart-table-streams")
    print(entries)
    for i, (entry, stream) in enumerate(zip(entries,streams)):
         song = entry.find('strong').get_text()
         artist = entry.find('span').get_text()[3:]
         play_count = stream.get_text()
         rows.append([song, artist, date, play_count, i+1])
return(rows)
```

I tried printing the entries and streams but get a blank value

```
entries = soup.find_all("td", class_ = "chart-table-track")
streams = soup.find_all("td", class_= "chart-table-streams")
```

I have copied/referenced this from  [Here](https://gist.github.com/hktosun/d4f98488cb8f005214acd12296506f48)
and tried running the full script but that gives error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'  in the country  function. Hence I tried for a smaller section as above.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: I expected to get some data with with soup.find_all("td",class= "chart-table-track"). So my question is how do i fix this as i am unable to understand the reason for not getting any data when it was expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoneType suggests that is doesn't find the "Entries" or "Streams", if you print soup it will show you that the selectors set up for entries and streams does not exist.

After checking your soup object, it seems that Cloudflare is blocking your access to Spotify and you need to complete a CAPTCHA to get around this. There is a library set up for bypassing cloudflare called "cloudscraper".

Comment: Thanks using that library worked for me. Honestly don't know why is your answer downvoted but thanks :D

Comment: Possibly somebody is just mad at your question. You're welcome :)

Comment: @kchahat20 if you deal with the problem could you please give us some extra hints how did you deal it?